# Solana JSON RPC API parameters encoding

Tags: rust, blockchain, solana, decentralized-applications

Is there any documentation or paper about how exactly are rust parameters types encoded via JSON RPC API interaction?
Like for ethereum: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/abi-spec.html

There are some good abstraction tools like web3js to encode simple types like integers, but i have not found any paper about how to encode arrays or structs.

It is insanely hard for me to get into solana intricacies after building ethereum dApps, so it would be great if you share any other good specifications.

TY!

Comment: So, you submit Transactions which contain Instructions which contain Instruction Data that is sent to the onchain program. Are you talking about Instruction Data or are you referring to the onchain programs serialization/deserialization of account data?

Comment: @FrankC. Instruction Data. But onchain serialization/deserialization of account data isn't clear for me too though :)

Comment: @FrankC.
For example: in ethereum i know that contract has method with signature like "approve(address,amount)". Data which i would send to contract via JSON RPC is prepared next way: i take first 10 bytes of signature's keccak256 hash, then append it with encoded paramteres (as it said in specification above), and then just send it to contract address.

The reason i made this post is that i can't figure out same algorythm for Solana contracts, especially how parameters are encoded

Comment: perhaps a bit late, but reading the source code for anchor is usually most helpful https://project-serum.github.io/anchor/ts/modules/web3.html

Answer (score 0):

So each program is unique in this regard although many follow a similar model. This is something that you must find the source code or documentation for the specific program you want to call.

If you only have the source code there is commonly, following good practices, an
`instruction.rs` file that identifies each of the instructions and what data they expect. It may also specify what convention of serialization is used so that would clue you in to what you need to do on the client side that submits the instruction.

In addition, for data serialization/deserialization, following good practices there may be a
`state.rs` or `account_state.rs` that shows you how the program serializes/deserializes account data.

The latter giving you the understanding of how you would need to deserialize an AccountInfo data array to see results in the client.